# Не запускается приложение на Laravel из-за проблем с ключом шифрования

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.3.

Не запускается приложение. Вылетает:

> RuntimeException in Encrypter.php line 43: The only supported ciphers
>   are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths.

Нагуглил три команды для решения проблемы:

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Выполнил все три, проблема плевать на них хотела и не собирается уходить. По-прежнему выскакивает та же ошибка.

Comment: Это новое приложение? Вы создали .env файл в корне?

Comment: .env файл был. Проблема появилась после переноса на production

Comment: Запускаем команду "php artisan key:generate". Копируем ключ в файл ".env" в строку "APP_KEY=base64:ВАШ_КЛЮЧ_ЗДЕСЬ". Затем запускаем команду "php artisan config:clear", а после команду "php artisan config:cache".

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вот что значит не вчитываться в английские слова. Надо было Вам оформить это дело в "ответе", я бы отметил, как правильный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запускаем команду `php artisan key:generate`.

Копируем ключ в файл `.env` в строку `APP_KEY=base64:ВАШ_КЛЮЧ_ЗДЕСЬ`.

Затем запускаем команду `php artisan config:clear`, а после команду `php artisan config:cache`.